# Xamarin - Read Assets from Shared Project

Tags: xamarin

I am using Xamarin for Android / iOS development. I have added a Shared Project within Xamarin solution. One of the functionality in the Shared project would be read assets within Android. However, **AssetManager or Assets is not available from the Shared project**. Any clue on how this can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late - hope it still helps somebody.
You can use
https://github.com/juergenkoller/PCLStorage

It has a GetFileFromAppBundleAsync function. You can place your file inside the asset folder of your Android project and do something like this:

```
var file = await FileSystem.Current.GetFileFromAppBundleAsync("your file.xyz", new CancellationToken(false));
var content = await file.ReadAllTextAsync ();
```